# sed command to replace a string with special characters with another string with special characters

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed

I have a string with special characters called /data/user/sam and I want to replace it with /data/sam and write it in a text file called sample.txt. I am able to do so but it keeps on appending the result in sample.txt on running the command again. It should replace it whole each time instead of appending.

Here is the snippet:-

```
sed 's/"\/data\/user\/sam"/"\/data\/sam"/g' sample.txt
```

Output in sample.txt on running twice

```
/data/sam/data/sam
```

It should be:

```
/data/sam
```

on running as many times as user wants.

Comment: I cannot replicate your example. Are the double quotes supposed to be in the regex or the input? What is the result of running your command *once*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the delimiter of the pattern (here I choose `#`, which may not clash with pathnames):

```
sed 's#/data/user/sam#/data/sam#g' sample.txt
```

Use option `-i` to perform in-place substitution.

Comment: That's a good tip, but it does not answer the question.  It should be a comment, instead.